# Can't pass mysqli connection to class

Tags: php, mysqli, connection

I am trying to pass a mysqli connection to a class for it to use prepared statements. However, I am missing something and it is not working.  What a i doing wrong?

The following code outputs "no"

**index.php**

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'my_database';
$db_user = 'my_user';
$db_password = 'my_password';

$con = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die(mysqli_connect_error()); 
}

$obj = new Obj( $con );
```

**obj.php**

```
Class Obj
{
    public function __construct( mysqli $con )
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FOM myTable";
        if($con->prepare( $sql ))
        {
            echo "yes";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "no";
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: check ur code, `if($con->prepare( $slq ))` , u pass `$slq` instead of `$sql`

Comment: Sorry. That was just a typo when writing this post. I have edited it now

Comment: in constructor, use `print_r($con)` to check whether u get $con or not?

Comment: Use `var_dump` on `$con` to see what you get instead of what you expect.

Comment: If i print_r($con) i get "mysqli Object ( ) "

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FOM myTable";`  edit the query, FOM<=>FROM

Comment: Just another typo.  Really must check my posts before I hit the submit button. Sorry bout that. I have been digging around, and discovered the problem is nothing to do with the class, but with the connection itself. I still don't know the answer, but to avoid confusion with others searching this forum, i will raise it as a separate question.  (And will check my spelling this time). Thanks for your help so far

Comment: always use, print_r(), var_dump(), die(), exit(), echo function to debug your code... u will get ur answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had failed to pass a mysqli connection to your class, you'd be getting a fatal error on this line:

```
public function __construct( mysqli $con )
                             ^^^^^^
```

But not only the constructor starts running fine, you can even access a class method:

```
if($con->prepare( $sql ))
```

To sum up, all that happens is that `mysqli::prepare()` returns `false` because there was an error while preparing the SQL statement. I'm not familiar with mysql but you can probably get the exact error message with [mysqli::$error_list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php) or [mysqli::$error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php):

```
    if($con->prepare( $slq ))
    {
        echo "yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "no: " . $con->error;
    }
```

If `SELECT * FOM myTable` is the actual query, I suppose it's a simple syntax error since you've misspelt `FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Obj {
  public function __construct( mysqli $con ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
    if($con->prepare( $sql ))       //here, u pass $slq before
    {
        echo "yes";
    }
    else {
        echo "no";
    }
  }
}
```